# Как обратится к строковому ресурсу через составное имя?

Tags: java, android, android-resources

Есть ресурс:

```
<string name="kit_14">Вася</string>
```

Пытаюсь обратится к нему:

```
String cnt = "14";
menu1.getMenu().add(0, 0, 0, getString(R.string."kit_"+cnt));
```

Не прокатывает. Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
public static String getResourceString(String name, Context context) {
    int nameResourceID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(name,
            "string", context.getApplicationInfo().packageName);
    if (nameResourceID == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "No resource string found with name " + name);
    } else {
        return context.getString(nameResourceID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Для получения ресурса по его имени необходимо:

1. Получить идентификатор ресурса по его имени;
2. Получить сам ресурс по его идентификатору.

Получить идентификатор ресурса по его имени можно с помощью метода:

```
int getIdentifier (String name, String defType, String defPackage)
```

, где:

1. `name` – имя ресурса;
2. `defType` – тип ресурса, например, `string`;
3. `defPackage` – имя пакета, которое можно получить, например, с помощью метода `getPackageName()`.

Получить ресурс по его идентификатору можно с помощью соответствующих методов, например, для строкового ресурса:

```
String getString (int resId)
```

На Вашем примере:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("kit_" + cnt, "string", getPackageName());
String str = getString(resId);
```

Методы `getResources()` и `getString(...)` вызываются из класса, наследующего класс `Context`.